# Laravel 4 Eager Loading with ::find()

Tags: laravel-4

Say I have two tables **shifts** and **users**. Each `shift` would have a user associated with it. I wanted to get the JSON return of the shift and the user. I tried the following command:

```
return Shift::find($id)->with('User')->get()
```

and this doesn't work. However, this does:

```
return Shift::where('id', '=', $id)->with('User')->get()
```

Why? How can I use the first command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` and `find` are both *execution* methods. That is, they will fire the query and return a result. Basically, you shouldn't be using two of them in a single call. It's either `find`, `get`, or `first`, not a combination of them.

`find` will return a single model and create a condition based on the primary key of the model, usually `where('id', '=', $id)`

`get`will return a collection of models.

`first` will return a single model.

It sounds like you need:

```
return Shift::with('user')->find($id);
```

Where `user` is the relationship method on your `Shift` model.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```